# How do I use subdomains with NGINX?

Tags: nginx, digital-ocean, nginx-location, nginx-config

Trying to set up a subdomain on my digitalocean server using NGINX. Unfortunately, none of the things I tried have worked out so far. No error is shown, yet the site won't be fetched on the subdomain, only the main domain. Below is my config files:

/etc/nginx/nginx.conf:

```
user www-data;
worker_processes auto;
pid /run/nginx.pid;
include /etc/nginx/modules-enabled/*.conf;

events {
    worker_connections 768;
    # multi_accept on;
}

http {

    ##
    # Basic Settings
    ##

    sendfile on;
    tcp_nopush on;
    tcp_nodelay on;
    keepalive_timeout 65;
    types_hash_max_size 2048;
    # server_tokens off;

    server_names_hash_bucket_size 64;
    # server_name_in_redirect off;

    include /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    default_type application/octet-stream;

    ##
    # SSL Settings
    ##

    ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2; # Dropping SSLv3, ref: POODLE
    ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;

    ##
    # Logging Settings
    ##

    access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;
    error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;

    ##
    # Gzip Settings
    ##

    gzip on;

    # gzip_vary on;
    # gzip_proxied any;
    # gzip_comp_level 6;
    # gzip_buffers 16 8k;
    # gzip_http_version 1.1;
    # gzip_types text/plain text/css application/json application/javascript text/xml application/xml application/xml+rss text/javascript;
    ##
    # Virtual Host Configs
    ##

    include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
    include /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*;
}


#mail {
#       # See sample authentication script at:
#       # http://wiki.nginx.org/ImapAuthenticateWithApachePhpScript
# 
#       # auth_http localhost/auth.php;
#       # pop3_capabilities "TOP" "USER";
#       # imap_capabilities "IMAP4rev1" "UIDPLUS";
# 
#       server {
#               listen     localhost:110;
#               protocol   pop3;
#               proxy      on;
#       }
# 
#       server {
#               listen     localhost:143;
#               protocol   imap;
#               proxy      on;
#       }
#}
```

/etc/nginx/site-available/ava-tms.com:

```
server {

    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80;

    server_name ava-tms.com www.ava-tms.com;
    root /var/www/ava-tms.com/live/;
    index index.html index.htm;

    location / {
            try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
    } 
}
```

/etc/nginx/site-available/beta.ava-tms.com:

```
server {

    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80;

    server_name beta.ava-tms.com www.beta.ava-tms.com;
    root /var/www/ava-tms.com/beta/;
    index index.html index.htm;

    location / {
            try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
    } 
}
```

Thanks in advance for the help.

Comment: can you share ```nginx.conf``` file ? and did you make a soft link ```beta.ava-tms.com``` to ```/etc/nginx/site-enabled/beta.ava-tms.com``` ?

Comment: @ThanhNguyenVan Did indeed soft link them... And I've put the nginx.conf file into the original question! :)

Comment: move your file ```/etc/nginx/site-available/``` to ```/etc/nginx/sites-enabled/``` and restart your nginx it`s work

Comment: @YaserDarzi I have soft linked them? Tried it anyway, didn't work.

Comment: Did you create a DNS record for your subdomain that points to your droplet?

Comment: @0stone0 Nope, actually realized that it was the problem, thx though!

Answer (score 0):

As 0stone0 suggested, my problem was merely the lack of a dns record. Thx for the help.